# Command line parsing turning out "Empty path name is not legal"

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

Everything looks appropriate... Although the parsing isn't so robust.

Here are the arguments.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++)
        {
            if(args[0] == "-logpath" && (args[1].Contains("%") || args[1].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[1].Contains("\\")))
            {
                logpath = args[1];
            }
            if(args[2] == "-idpath" && (args[3].Contains("%") || args[3].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[3].Contains("\\")))
            {
                serverIDpath = args[3];
            }
            if(args[4] == "-queuepath" && (args[5].Contains("%") || args[5].ToLower().Contains("C") || args[5].Contains("\\")))
            {
                servqueuepath = args[5];
            }
            if(args[6] == "-ramlimit" && 0 < Convert.ToInt32(args[7]))
            {
                ramlimit = args[7];
            }
            if(args[8] == "-paramsname" && (!args[11].Contains("\\") || !args[11].Contains(":")) && (args[11].Contains(".cmd") || args[11].ToLower().Contains(".txt") || args[11].Contains("bat")))
            {
                spname = args[9];
            }
            //etc.
```

The two lines it issues errors about.

```
        if(!File.Exists(serverIDpath + sidname))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(serverIDpath + sidname, "default");
        }
        if(!File.Exists(logpath))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(logpath, "");
        }
```

The batch file looks alright.

```
set rootpath=%userprofile%\desktop\filebin
cd %rootpath%
fileread -logpath %rootpath%\fr_log.txt -idpath %rootpath%\ -queuepath %rootpath%\queuecheck.txt -ramlimit 1600 -paramsname serverparams.cmd -idname serverid.cmd -resourcetxtpath %rootpath%\ramcheck.txt -sysresource %rootpath%\sysresourceoutput.exe -updatepath %rootpath%\update.bat -servelogpath %rootpath%\fsrv_log.txt -fileserve %rootpath%\FileServe.exe
```

Here is an image of the error output:
http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/25/i9tr.png

My question is, well, hm I must be missing something.

Comment: How to you expect `args[3].ToLower().Contains("C")` to ever be true? (Or for any of the other arguments...) Are you logging the value of `serverIDpath`, `sidname` or `logpath` anywhere? My guess is that one of those is not what you expect it to be. This approach to command line parsing is a bit arcane, mind you - why should all the command line arguments be in that particular order? And why are you looking at `args[11]` while determining `paramsname`?

Comment: I suppose.. if the person hard-coded the paths, and it so happened to be on drive C, but yes. Haha, yes they are each global variables. Yes it is. I did a run-through of the conditions and didn't proof-read.

Comment: What is your error? Where is the *actual* code producing it? Do you really have a loop that never enters? Do you really expect all of your  command line arguments to appear in one set order, always? How can a lower cased string ever contain an upper cased "C"? The mind boggles...

Comment: The actual code producing is one that gets me. It is below the list of arguments. Yes, I tried another, probably more successful command line parsing that didn't need exact order, but reverted to this to troubleshoot .. :)

Comment: %userprofile% - is not change to string?

Comment: I should upload an image link of the output..!